# Porque no puedo subir mis archivos a github

Tags: github

Buenas tardes no he podido subir mis archivos a github lo que hice fue un

```
git add -A
git commit -m "mensaje"
git push origin master
```

cuando hago push me aparece este mensaje

```
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

pero no me aparece los archivos en github.

Comment: aparece esto On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   Hola-Mundo/.browserslistrc

Answer (score 0):

Realiza un git status para asegurarte que si se incluyo tus archivos, adicional a eso realiza un git add. Pará que suban todos los archivos.